Difference between "with X as Y" in Python and try-with-resources in Java
I'm a bit new to Python still, and I got a question about the nuances of "with X as Y" in Python. It seems to be similar to a try-with-resources in Java, but I'm wondering what the differences are (so I don't make assumptions). So, what are the differences between the following two:
try (InputStream in = getInput()) {
    // Java -- Do stuff
}

and
with getInput() as source:
    # Python -- Do stuff


One difference in semantics is that with the following Java block:
try (InputStream in = getInput()) {
    // Java -- Do stuff
}
...
InputStream in2 = getInput();
assert(in2.getClass() == in.getClass());

the variable in has the actual value returned by getInput(). But with Python, this is not necessarily the case:
with getInput() as source:
    # Python -- Do stuff
...
source2 = getInput()
# Now source and source2 are not necessarily the same type

Here, getInput() returns an object that has a method called __enter__(). The variable source is then assigned whatever value __enter()__ returns. It is a very common practice for __enter()__ to return self in order to avoid surprises, but it's not an actual requirement.

That is definitely an important difference. More customizable in Python, how useful

Note that the call to getInput in the with statement isn't special; you can write inp = getInput(); with inp as source: ... and inp.__enter__ is still called. Often, you just don't care about the context manager except for its protocol methods being called, and don't need an explicit reference to it.

The with statement is more general than the try-with-resources statement. A with statement is a general framework that can be used to invoke arbitrary code on entry to and on exit from the body of the with statement. It does this by using a context manager, which is any object with appropriately defined __enter__ and __exit__ methods. As a very simple example:
class Foo:
    def __enter__(self):
        print("Entering")
        return 9

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("Exiting")


f = Foo()
with f as x:
    print(x)

will output
Entering
9
Exiting

just as if you had written
f = Foo()
x = f.__enter__()
print(x)
f.__exit__()

(For simplicity, I'm ignoring exception handling. Information about any exception raised in the body of the with statement is passed to the __exit__ method for possibly handling and/or re-raising.)
See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with for a more complete description of what an arbitrary with statement "desugars" to.

That's a great example of how it actually works. Also explains why I was getting a certain error with the way I was using with-as
